# Trying to append to class in current view but results in appending to other views

Tags: backbone.js

I am rendering a view for each item in a collection, each of those items contain a list that I am trying to append to an ul but they are being appended to the ul of other views.

View:

```
    initialize: function(){

    },

    render: function(){
        var current = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(_.template(cTemplate, current));

        var items = this.model.toJSON().items;
        items.forEach(function(item){
            this.$('.list').append('<li>'+item.attributes.price+'</li>');
        });

        return this;
    }
```

Template:

```
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

I am trying to append to this.$('.list') which I thought would mean I am appending the price of each item only to the class of my template in the current view. It appears I cannot reference it like this because the prices are appended to all list classes in views rendered before the current one.

I am wondering how I prevent appending to all of the same classes on the same page and just to the one from the template of my current view.

Comment: note: If items is an array, then the `this` in the `foreach` function will not be your view, but rather a window. So this.$ is the global jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ul` is the `tagName` of this view class, you can simply append to this.

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  this.$el.append('<li>'+item.attributes.price+'</li>');
});
```

or, `ul.list` is a child element, you can do this

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  this.$el.find('ul.list').append('<li>'+item.attributes.price+'</li>');
});
```

**Note**: This pattern may not be maintainable in future when complexity increases. You can considering creating individual view for each item if those items has interactions.